# Data extract and import from CSV with foreign keys - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, multi-tenant

I have a multi tenant database. My requirement is to extract a single tenant's data from a database and insert in to other database.

So I have 2 tables: users and identities.
users table has foreign key identity_id connected with identities table
There can be many identities and users under a customer.

I am extracting the data to a csv file and inserting into new database from the csv file.
primary key is set to auto increment, so users and identities table generate id while inserting data from csv.

Table data from existing database

Users table

```
| id  | identity_id |
| --- | ------------|
| 86  | 70          |
| 193 | 127         |
| 223 | 131         |
```

Identities table

```
|id |name        |email            |
|---|------------|-----------------|
|70 |Alon muscle |muscle@test.com  |
|131|james       |james@james.com  |
|127|watson      |watson@watson.com|
```

Now identity_id is the foreign key in users table mapping to identities table.

I am trying to insert users and identities data to new database
So primary key will be auto incremented for users and identities.
The problem comes here with foreign key.
How can I maintain foreign_key relationship as I have multiple users and identities records?

Comment: You are missing significant necessary information. Take a few minuets to review [ask]. Specifically, update your question to include table definitions (ddl) including PK/FKs, sample data (as csv), and the expected results *of that data*. All as text - **no images**.

Comment: updated tables details @Belayer

Comment: I tried copying data to a staging table but unable to figure out how to use that staging table to map foreign key relationships

Answer (score 0):

Well you did not actually provide details on your tables, that would be the actual definitions (ddl). Nor provide the CVS contents, which I assume your stage table contains same. However with the test data provided and a couple assumptions the following demonstrates a method to load your data. The method is to build a procedure which uses the stage table to load `identities` table then selects the generates id from the email provided to populate `users` table. Assumptions:

1. email must be unique in `identities` (at least in lower case).
2. stage table reflects name and email for `identities`.

Procedure to load identities and users.

```
    create or replace procedure generate_user_idents() 
      language sql $
        insert into identities(name, email)
             select name, email
               from stage
              on conflict (low_email) 
                  do nothing ; 
                 
    as $$
        insert into users(ident_id) 
             select ident.ident_id 
               from identities ident 
              where ident.low_email in 
                    ( select lower(email) 
                        from stage
                    ) ;
                   
    $$;
```

Script to clear and repopulate stage data then load stage to identities and users.

```
    do $$
    begin
        execute 'truncate table stage'; 
    
       -- replace the following with your \copy to load stage 
        insert into stage(name, email)
             values ( 'Alon muscle', 'muscle@test.com' )
                  , ( 'watson',      'watson@watson.com')         
                  , ( 'james',       'james@james.com' ); 
            
        call generate_user_idents(); 
    end ; 
    $$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=083b99f2a9372454db1f70c2d2151574). Since the demo generates the ids, it does not exactly match your provided values, but close. As it stands the procedure would be happy generating duplicates should you fail to clear the `stage` table or reenter the same values into it. You have to decide how to handle that.